# Montecarlo Markov Chain trouble! Changing Series to Float?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, montecarlo, markov-chains

I'm trying to write a Montecarlo Markov chain algorithm, but when I try to run operations with data from the attached file (http://www.iiap.res.in/astrostat/School07/R/COUP551_rates.dat) I get the error:

```
 The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()
```

in the line

```
logMHratio = (np.sum(data[0:int(propk)])*np.log(currtheta)+np.sum(data[int((propk+1)):n])*np.log(currlambda)-propk*currtheta- (n-propk)*currlambda - (np.sum(data[1:int(currk)])*np.log(currtheta)+np.sum(data[int((currk+1)):n])*np.log(currlambda)-currk*currtheta- (n-currk)*currlambda)).
```

I think the problem is these operations output a series when I need a Float.
Full code:

```
data= pd.read_csv("COUP551_rates.dat" , skiprows= 1, delim_whitespace=True, error_bad_lines=False )
k_estimado= 10
def sampler(it=1000, data=data):
    data['Tbin'] = data['Tbin'].astype(float)
    data['Cts'] = data['Cts'].astype(float)
    n=len(data)
    ## each row corresponds to one of 5 parameters in order: theta,lambda,k,b1,b2
    ## each column corresponds to a single state of the Markov chai
    cadenam= np.zeros((5,it))
    acc= 0 
    k_inic = np.floor(n/2) 
    ## starting values for Markov chain
    ## This is somewhat arbitrary but any method that produces reasonable values for each parameter is usually adequate.

    cadenam[:,0] = np.array([1,1,k_inic,1,1])
    
    for i in range(1, it): 
        
        currtheta = cadenam[0,i-1]
        currlambda = cadenam[1,i-1]
        currk = cadenam[2,i-1]
        currb1 = cadenam[3,i-1]
        currb2 = cadenam[4,i-1]
        
        ## sample from full conditional distribution of theta (Gibbs update)
        currtheta = np.random.gamma(shape=np.sum(data[1:int(currk)])+0.5, scale=currb1/(currk*currb1+1), size=1)
        
        ## sample from full conditional distribution of lambda (Gibbs update)
        currlambda = np.random.gamma(shape=np.sum(data[int((currk+1)):n])+0.5, scale=currb2/((n-currk)*currb2+1), size=1)
        
        ## sample from full conditional distribution of k (Metropolis-Hastings update)
        x=np.arange(2,n)
        propk = np.random.choice(x, size=1) # draw one sample at random from uniform{2,..(n-1)}

        ## Metropolis accept-reject step (in log scale)
        logMHratio = (np.sum(data[0:int(propk)])*np.log(currtheta)+np.sum(data[int((propk+1)):n])*np.log(currlambda)-propk*currtheta- (n-propk)*currlambda - (np.sum(data[1:int(currk)])*np.log(currtheta)+np.sum(data[int((currk+1)):n])*np.log(currlambda)-currk*currtheta- (n-currk)*currlambda))
        logalpha = min(0,logMHratio) # alpha = min(1,MHratio)
        x1= np.log(np.random.uniform(size=1))
        if  x1 < logalpha : # accept if unif(0,1)<alpha, i.e. accept with probability alpha, else stay at current state
            acc = acc + 1 # increment count of accepted proposals
            currk = propk
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is, that `data` is a DataFrame. Thus `logMHratio` is still a DataFrame, but due to the sums, now with shape (1,2), i.e. `data['Tbin'] = number` and `data['Cts'] = someothernumber`. Then `min(0, logMHration)` doesn't know what to do.

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, you might want to use `data = data.set_index('Tbin')` or replace `data` in your calculations with `data['Cts']`.